# What is the beat way to solve "mutable borrow occurs here" in this situation?

Tags: apache-kafka, rust

I am a beginner in rust.

I know what happened, spend a whole afternoon to try, and finally, could not find any solution...

Need help from kind people T_T

```
use kafka::client::{FetchOffset, GroupOffsetStorage, KafkaClient};

fn main() {
  let mut client = KafkaClient::new(vec!["localhost:9092".to_owned()]);
  client.load_metadata_all().unwrap();
  client.set_group_offset_storage(GroupOffsetStorage::Kafka);
  for topic in client.topics().names() {
    let topic_offsets = client.fetch_topic_offsets(topic, FetchOffset::Latest).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", topic_offsets);

    let group_topic_offsets = client.fetch_group_topic_offsets("test", topic).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", group_topic_offsets);
    for (partition_index, tp_offset) in topic_offsets.iter().enumerate() {
      println!("partition {}'s lag = {}", partition_index, tp_offset.offset - group_topic_offsets[partition_index].offset)
    }
  }
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `client` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:11:31
   |
7  |   for topic in &mut client.topics().names() {
   |                ----------------------------
   |                |    |
   |                |    immutable borrow occurs here
   |                immutable borrow later used here
...
11 |     let group_topic_offsets = client.fetch_group_topic_offsets("test", topic).unwrap();
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Comment: Just collect the topic names into a `Vec<String>`? Alternatively, see if the information you're looking for is available on the topics themselves to avoid having to go through the Client again.

Comment: In case it's not obvious what Masklinn proposed, you can change `for topic in client.topics().names() { ... }` to `for topic in  client.topics().names().collect::<Vec<_>>() { ... }`. That way you will first collect the names into a `Vec` and free up `client` for other things.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works very well now!